# ArcMap edit does not save polygon

Tags: arcmap, editing

Editor doesnt save when click finish sketch . It becomes unvisible. I try it  different locations this time it is visible, no problem. I uploaded video For clarify .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from your video that you are doing your editing in the "layout view" aka the view you use to create a final output map, I would switch to "Data view". Additionally, it looks like you may have some projection issues within your ArcMap session so it would be worthwhile to resolve those before editing and then you should either:

a) Start a new ArcMap session and add the layer you want to edit. This will rule out the potential of a corrupted ArcMap session.
or

b) Add the layer to your existing ArcMap session and ensure that it is one of the top most layers (so that it isn't being obscured by other polygons for example).

If neither of these options work, feel free to edit your post with what else you tried and why/how it didn't work as expected and we can go from there.

Comment: Definitely switch to Data View before trying anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that I have two layers with same name, when editing I choose another one.